# pic33f UART Problems

Tags: pic, uart

I've been tearing my hair out at this for a while.
I have a dsPIC33FJ16GS502 and I've been trying to get it to transmit a single character to my computer but so far, I have been getting absolute garbage:

[image: Serial Terminal]

The uC should be sending 'b' instead of 0x89.  I have a gist of my code available [here](https://gist.github.com/superkittens/9244847).

I have a 16 Mhz crystal connected to OSC1 and OSC2 with two 27 pF capacitors attached.  I also have a 10 uF electrolytic cap at Vcap (datasheet says I should really use tantalum but I don't have any at the moment).  I'm using a pickit 2 to program the uC.  The TX pin is connected to a FTDI FT232 usb-serial converter.  Baud rate is 9600.

Maybe I'm missing something really basic.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:  Here's a photo of my setup:
[image: Setup]

Edit 2:  Measurements from a logic analyzer.  There seems to be a fluctuation between 0x89 and a comma:
[image: LA 1]

[image: la 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The level information was confirmed to be okay (TTL out inverted-> TTL in inverted on an FTDI USB bridge) but I've left it in at the end of this answer in case anyone else needs it.

The easiest way to deal with this sort of troubleshooting is to break it down and confirm the bits are working. An oscilloscope (or logic analyzer) will confirm that the timing is correct and that the signal is not inverted and is the proper levels. That eliminates potential issues with BRG setting, clock source or frequency settings and so on.

If there is a mismatch between the number of start and stop bits or length at receiver and transmitter, then it can show up when characters are sent one after the other with no space, so it can help to space them out (it also makes it easier to interpret the logic analyzer or 'scope images). Not in this case, since it's interrupt-driven but it's even possible the buffer could be overwritten.

I have had good luck using [Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) as a terminal program, also Teraterm and Putty to a lesser extent.

---

Original guess as to problem (left for historical reasons).

If you are not using an RS-232 level converter, that could be your problem. A typical unit is the [MAX232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf).

As well as shifting levels to appropriate voltages, it inverts the signal.

Most RS-232 receivers will respond to 0/5V signals, but the inverted signal will lead to incorrect data being received.

From the datasheet linked above:

[image]

The chip contains charge pumps to get +/- 8.5V signals from a single 5V supply, with only a few external ceramic or electrolytic capacitors.

You could try it out with an inverter if you don't have any of these chips around.

Comment: I don't think a level converter is the issue (your answer did remind me to add the bit where I use a ftdi seial-usb converter.  That would be a useful bit of info!).  The uC output is TTL with no inversion happening.

Comment: UART output is TTL levels, but also inverted from RS-232. Are you sure you've got inversion in there?

Comment: I'm positive I don't have inversion.  I just took a look at the logic analyzer measurements and flipping the bits doesn't seem to correspond to the right character

Comment: Okay, I don't see anything obvious. Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: Can you put some delays between the characters, at least a couple milliseconds?

Comment: I've added a for loop at the ISR as a crude form of delay.  This actually seems to be working.  The right characters are being displayed :)

Comment: Maybe something to do with your terminal program setup? I usually use Realterm.

Comment: I think I know what happened.  The logic analyzer (and even the terminal) couldn't find the right position of the start and stop bits so it sort of arbitrarily picked a spot to start.  If you look at the waveforms (without looking at the dots), you can't really find the start/stop bits!  Usually the line would be high for some time before transmitting the next byte.  So the uart was doing fine, spitting out 'b'=0x62=0b1100010.  The receiving end just having a hard time where the signal was actually starting and stopping.